# store url in conf file to be used as global variable

Tags: angularjs, web, global

My app curently has several controllers and each one of them uses an url to do request for the view it works for.

My url look like this : htttp://myurl/requestSpecificHeader.

Url is currently hard coded which can't do. I would like it to be stored in a config.txt or .json or something easy to rewrite, than get it to my app.js and make it a global variable to be used in one controller. As my app is fairly small (4 views) I only have one file that hold all my controllers and services.

What would be the best way to proceed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare it as a constant:

```
angular.module('App').constant('myUrl', 'http://myurl/');
```

Now you can inject this value into your controllers:

```
app.controller('Ctrl', function(myUrl){
    var thisUrl = myUrl + 'requestSpecificHeader'
});
```

Comment: I was meaning to get the url from a txt file to would you know how ?

Comment: It is possible, but it'll be finicky. Why do you want to do this? Loading it as an Angular constant or value is the best way of doing this.

Comment: I want the final users to be able to modify the url without opening actual code

Comment: Right... Firstly the first line of code in my example can be literally entirely self contained in a JS file, so there isn't much scope for confusion. But in general loading the url through a text file is a bad idea. In any case, if you're sending requests to the same url that the site is on you can simply do the requests to `/requestSpecificHeader` and that will send your requests to your url anyway.

Comment: okay great ill head your advice, and I wil just create a README file to show how to modify the adress; thanks for your time anyway, great answers

Answer (score 0):

Create a service using the angular.constant and add all your end points to the service as constants.

```
    App.constant('REGION_CONFIG_APIS', {
        getCountries: '/api/Country/GetCounties',
        addCountry: '/api/Country/AddCountry'
    });
```

Then in you service, inject the endpoints and use it.

```
App.service('regionConfigService', function ( REGION_CONFIG_APIS,$q,DataService) {

this.getCountryData = function () {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    DataService.GetData(REGION_CONFIG_APIS.getCountries)
       .then(function (data) {
           deferred.resolve(data);
       });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```